# Tips to share container between 2 objects?

Tags: c++, stl

I have some STL containers that i need to share between objects of 2 different types - say A & B. The container is defined in class A and used as reference in class B. Since STL containers are not thread safe, I was planning to define `boost::mutex` in A and store it as reference in class B.

That plan has obviously failed since I realize that `boost::mutex` is not copyable. I can't move the container out of class A or provide a wrapper over the container. What would you do here?

And why can't mutexes be copied?

Comment: Are `A` and `B` always doing work on different threads?

Comment: Create class C that owns the containers and provides the thread-safe operations needed by A and B.

Comment: What do you think the effect of copying a mutex should be? What happens if someone locks one but not the other?

Comment: A copy-constructor typically is associated with the idea of "value semantics". I.e. after copying, you have two *independent* objects that compare equal. This isn't possible for resource-managing (RAII) type (either the two copies wouldn't be independent, or they wouldn't compare equal). In fact, there isn't even a comparison defined for `boost::mutex`, probably because the only reasonable definition would be identity (`a` is equal to `b` IFF `a` *is* `b`).

Comment: DyP, no this is more related to concept itself than value semantics or RAII

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I can follow, but if you want to share a mutex between two instances of a class to protect a shared resource, why not just use `boost::shared_ptr<boost::mutex>` to have access to the mutex from both instances?

This should be a general strategy when you need to shared resources, you might also consider using `boost::shared_ptr` for the container itself, but without seeing your code, it's hard to provide some specific suggestions.

Comment: We are talking about objects of 2 diff class types sharing the same container. One has it defined inside itself and other keeps a reference.

Comment: @Fanatic23 I understand that, but I don't think you understand what I'm suggesting? Initialize the `shared_ptr<mutext>` in `A` and copy the `shared_ptr` to `B`. A shared pointer is copyable and you can access the stored mutex from both classes. If this is not clear to you, I think you have a more fundamental problem wrt resource handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sample
{
  std::vector<int> v;
private:
  struct Mut;
};

struct Sample::Mut
{
  boost::mutex mut_;
};
```

or

```
class Sample {
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::mutex> mutt;
    Sample() : mutt(new boost::mutex) {}
};
```

now you can refer to the `boost::mutex` of this sample in other objects providing an access to mutex wrapper, or maybe directly initializing these objects with copy of `Mut` structure or `boost::shared_ptr`. `boost::shared_ptr` is *copyable* and all its copies **will share** given mutex.

---

> And why can't mutexes be copied?

Because mutex is *noncopyable*. This is it derives from `boost::noncopyable`:

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

class mutex:
    boost::noncopyable
{
```

> Class noncopyable is a base class.  Derive your own class from
>   noncopyable when you want to prohibit copy construction and copy
>   assignment.

You don't need their copy in fact because it would be useless, but rather you want to share same instance in many objects and refer to a single mutex which guards access to single resource.

from `<boost/noncopyable.hpp>` :

```
//  Private copy constructor and copy assignment ensure classes derived from
//  class noncopyable cannot be copied.

//  Contributed by Dave Abrahams

namespace noncopyable_  // protection from unintended ADL
{
  class noncopyable
  {
   protected:
#ifndef BOOST_NO_DEFAULTED_FUNCTIONS
    BOOST_CONSTEXPR noncopyable() = default;
    ~noncopyable() = default;
#else
    noncopyable() {}
      ~noncopyable() {}
#endif
#ifndef BOOST_NO_DELETED_FUNCTIONS
        noncopyable( const noncopyable& ) = delete;
        noncopyable& operator=( const noncopyable& ) = delete;
#else
    private:  // emphasize the following members are private
      noncopyable( const noncopyable& );
      noncopyable& operator=( const noncopyable& );
#endif
  };
}

typedef noncopyable_::noncopyable noncopyable;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the implementation of `noncopyable` explains *why* a mutex has been deliberately made non-copyable.

Comment: @DyP you can [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) such question on SO, here it is only to emphasize that copy constructor and copy assignment members are private

Comment: and I always prefer to show some real code than just speculate (or mull out the theory). here you can see that indeed constructor of mutex is private

Comment: The reason why I wrote this comment is because I interpret the OP's question *"And why can't mutexes be copied?"* as *"Why have mutexes been made non-copyable?"* and not *"How have mutexes been made non-copyable?"*

Comment: this explains everything because definition of noncopyable answers first question but not second which is your interpretation